# Does the documentation or language definition for R remark on the intended usage of R's integers?

Tags: r, integer, cinterop

A common comment that I see made about R's integer type is that it's only really intended for communication with C code. Do any statement like this appear in any official part of R's documentation? I often catch myself making vectors like `integer(10)` under the impression that they'll be more efficient for my purposes, only to remember this folklore and reconsider if I should ever be using integers for code that never tries to communicate with C code.

Comment: R docs are [here](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html), although it's easier to search everything at once if you get the whole source tree (by downloading the source tarball or checking out a copy from the SVN repository)

Comment: @Henrik Ah, you're talking about "_Integer vectors exist so that data can be passed to C or Fortran code which expects them, and so that (small) integer data can be represented exactly and compactly._" in `?integer`? Yes, I was a fool to miss that.

Comment: Related: [Benefits of using integer values for constants rather than numeric values (e.g. 1L vs 1) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319577/benefits-of-using-integer-values-for-constants-rather-than-numeric-values-e-g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. This folklore probably comes from the fact that R is pretty loose about typing and coercion, so it's easy to end up with a floating-point variable by accident.

Integer types certainly save memory:

```r
> object.size(seq(1e8))
400000048 bytes
> object.size(seq(1e8)+0.1)
800000048 bytes
```

I haven't tried benchmarking to see if R uses faster routines for integer vs floating-point arithmetic, but you could.

I haven't looked carefully through *all* of R's documentation, but the only slightly relevant comment that turns up in a full-text search for "integer" in the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) is:

> In most cases,the  difference  between  an  integer  and  a  numeric  value  will  be  unimportant  as  R  will  do  the right thing when using the numbers.  There are, however, times when we would like to explicitly create an integer value for a constant.  We can do this by calling the function `as.integer` or using various other techniques ...

I did a `grep integer *.texi` in the `doc/manual` directory of the R source tree and didn't (in a quick skim) notice anything else that looked relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Ben Bolker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) advice, I checked the [seven R manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html). In addition to [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66297959/10319707), I found the following:

> For most purposes the user will not be concerned if the “numbers” in a numeric vector are integers, reals or even complex. Internally calculations are done as double precision real numbers, or double precision complex numbers if the input data are complex.
> <sub>[*An Introduction to R* Section 2.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic)</sub>

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) gives lots of guidance for making R communicate with C and Fortran, but it doesn't say anything about the integer typing's intent.

The last place to check is the [Full Reference Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf). You would have to be mad to do so - the word "integer" occurs over 1000 times. However, a quick look at the index reveals [the documentation for the integer class](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/integer). This gives us the answer is such plain English that I should not be forgiven for having missed it:

> Integer vectors exist so that data can be passed to C or Fortran code which expects them, and so that (small) integer data can be represented exactly and compactly.